# problema con transientmodel y abstractmodel

Tags: python, odoo

quiero hacer un reporte que muestre el libro mayor, para ello cree un **transientmodel** y un **abstractmodel** pero no consigo hacerlo funcionar ya que me aparece el siguiente error:

File "/mnt/c/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 4727, in ensure_one

```
raise ValueError("Expected singleton: %s" % self)
```

ValueError: Expected singleton: proyecto_rc.cuenta(1, 2)

La idea del sistema es que me muestre por cuenta el debe y haber que posee cada una de ella. He realizado el siguiente código para hacerlo funcionar pero no me funciona como dije anteriormente.

py wizard

**class Libro(models.TransientModel):**

```
_name='proyecto_rc.libro'

fecha_inicio = fields.Date(string="Fecha inicio", required=True)

fecha_termino = fields.Date(string="Fecha termino", required=True)

cuenta_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='proyecto_rc.cuenta', string='Cuenta')

@api.multi

def action_report(self):

    """Metodo que llama la lógica que genera el reporte"""


    datas={'ids': self.env.context.get('active_ids', [])}

    res = self.read(['fecha_inicio', 'fecha_termino'])

    res = res and res[0] or {}

    datas['form'] = res

    domain=[]

    if self.fecha_inicio:

        domain=[('create_date','<',self.fecha_inicio)]

    fields=['titulo','total_cuenta_debe','total_cuenta_haber']

    lmayor_data = self.env['proyecto_rc.cuenta'].search_read(domain,fields)

    datas['lmayor_data'] = lmayor_data

    return self.env['report'].get_action([], 'proyecto_rc.report_libromayor', data=datas)
```

py report:

**class report_libromayor(models.AbstractModel):**

```
_name = 'report.proyecto_rc.libromayor'

@api.model

def render_html(self, docids, data=None):

    data = data if data is not None else {}

    libromayor = self.env['proyecto_rc.cuenta'].browse(data.get('ids', data.get('active_ids')))

    docargs = {

        'doc_ids': data.get('ids', data.get('active_ids')),

        'doc_model': 'proyecto_rc.cuenta',

        'docs': libromayor,

        'data': dict(

            data

        ),

    }

    return self.env['report'].render('proyecto_rc.libromayor_template', docargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

El error no aparece en tu código, en alguna función le estas pasando la cuenta de id 1, 2 cuando solo le deberías de pasar una, de eso va el ensure_one, es un raise que trata de evitar que se cuele más de un records.

Ya que estás depurando, analiza y encuentra donde te salta el raise y mete la función en un for, para que lo recorra y vaya haciendo la función de uno en uno.

Comment: ahora no me sale el error pero solo me imprime el reporte sin ningun dato, si abro un chat y te invito me podrias guiar ?

Answer (score 0):

El Detalle Esta aquí al momento de tener mas de 1 registro te vota error, trata de implementar algún ciclo para el recorrido de los registros

```
docargs = {

    'doc_ids': data.get('ids', data.get('active_ids')),

    'doc_model': 'proyecto_rc.cuenta',

    'docs': libromayor,

    'data': dict(

        data

    ),

}
```

Como un ciclo *for* ejemplo:

```
for rec in self:
    rec.docargs = {

       'doc_ids': data.get('ids', data.get('active_ids')),

       'doc_model': 'proyecto_rc.cuenta',

       'docs': libromayor,

       'data': dict(data),

    }
```